# Detecting when Music has finished playing

Tags: android, libgdx, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm using libgdx to play some background music for a game I'm writing. I have an array of potential music to be played, and I would like that when the current song finishes, another one is chosen at random from the array.

The problem I'm having is working out when the Music is finished.

The Music class doesn't appear to have any event handlers I could attach to, nor does it have a way of telling me how long it'll take for particular music to finish.

The only idea which comes to mind involves polling

```
music.isPlaying()
```

On a loop of some sort, to be able to determine when its stopped. But this is an ugly solution in my opinion - and won't work if (say) the user has turned sound off.

Is there anything else I could do ?

Comment: Implement  MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener in your class. OnCompletion method will be called when music completes playback.In that method you can pick the random music from the array and start the player again .. hope this helped

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean extend libdgx to support the listener you mentioned, or in my personal class for handling the playing of music?

Comment: In your personal class... Refer this http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get it to work with the stable version of the library...

Comment: Did the onCompletion method get called at the end of the playback ? If not did you set music.setOnCompletionListener(this);

Comment: I can't find the listener itself. I found a bug report asking for the feature, and from what I can work out, its not in the 0.9.9 release. having been added later (the bug report suggests it was added in 5th July 2013) - http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1446

Comment: Are you sure you have the v0.9.9? I just checked and its there

Comment: It is there for sure. Maybe you are talking about `Sound`? With Sound there really is no way to know when it finished, thanks to the Android API. I'd suggest gdx-audio extension in this case, but it's much more low-level and not available for GWT/iOS.

Comment: Okay apparently I'm still on 0.9.6. And moving to 0.9.9 gives me a ton and a half of errors (no backward compatibility?) So apparently I'm still stuck.

Comment: Anyway, its a valid answer for 0.9.9 and higher. So post it as an answer and I'll accept it for posterity.

Comment: hey @Haedrian, have you solve this problem? how did u fix it?
thanks!

Comment: @chelo_c - Had to go up a version of libgdx to 0.9.9. There is no clean way of doing it in earlier versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest versions of LibGDX you can define a `OnCompletetionListener` for your `Music`. See [the documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html#setOnCompletionListener%28com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music.OnCompletionListener%29). It will be called when the current playback of your music reached the end.

When using `Sound` there is a known problem about this feature. With Sound there really is no way to know when it finished, thanks to the Android API which needs to be supported. I'd suggest the gdx-audio extension in this case, but it's much more low-level and not available for GWT/iOS. See [the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-audio).

Comment: I still get some miliseconds of delay.
The transaction between music loops doesn't sound good.